# Atlassian Bitbucket Server Precommit Issue getting files

Tags: bitbucket-server

I am writing a plugin for Bitbucket Server (previously known as Stash) which implements a precommit hook and runs the code through a separate program for to check the style of the submitted code meets guidelines and fails the pull request if it doesn't.

I currently have a plugin which gets a unique list of files/paths (relative to their location in the repository) and is able to execute and process the output from my Style checker which takes in a list of files as its input.

I am currently getting my list of files via the following code

```
Page<Change> changes = commitService.getChanges(new ChangesRequest.Builder(repository, refchange.getToHash()).sinceId(refchange.getFromHash()).build(), PAGE_REQUEST);

for (Change change : changes.getValues(){
    // get repository path
    fileList.append(change.getPath().toString() + " ");
}
```

My issue is when try and pass the files to my checking program (within the plugin) it says they don't exist. When I run the command "git status" within my plugin, git reports that it is not in a git repository. Could someone tell me where the default repository location would be or preferable how I can get an absolute path to the files to run my style checker on?

Comment: After digging more into this issue I have decided that the hook I was implementing was the not the a git pre-commit hook type and is more likely to be an implementation of a git server-side Pre-recieve hook.